# Best way to include a configuration in an Angular library module?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-module

I created multiple Angular module libraries that all require different configurations, e. g. the primary color or the URLs for different API endpoints. What is best practice to include that in an Angular module?

I am also thinking about making this available as an npm package. So any tips to integrate a configuration on that?

Comment: You can make a library with common configurations and import the library in other libraries.

Comment: But there should be an interface or something that defines what fields of data the library need to work.. ?

Comment: You can make one file like config.ts in that store all your ConfigSetting like export const data=[ { label:'Home', path:'home' }]